# Symfony2 security token cleared after redirect

Tags: security, symfony

I have built a login form, with a custom provider which successfully sets the auth token.

I can see the "logged in as" in the profiler, while on the redirect interception page. The form then redirects to my success page.

For some reason, my success page, doesn't recognise that I'm logged in and loops back to the login page.

```
security:
    encoders:
        EP\Common\Entity\User: sha1
        encode_as_base64: false

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class EP\Common\Entity\User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login_form:
            pattern: ^/cms/(login|logout)$
            security: false

        cms:
            pattern:  ^/cms/
            security: true
            provider: main
            form_login:
                check_path: /cms/login_check
                login_path: /cms/login
            logout:
                path:   /cms/logout
                target: /cms/login


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/cms/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
        - { path: /cms, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: You might want removing the firewall `login_form` because you are already allowing anonymous user to access the login page. Where do you save the sessions? Are you just using the default settings of Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered why this is.

I'd added these methods to my User class (notice the [0] on unserialize - doctrine was looking for the ID of the user based on the first character of the ID):

```
/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
 * String representation of object
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
 * @return string the string representation of the object or null
 */
public function serialize()
{

    return serialize($this->getId());
}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
 * Constructs the object
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.unserialize.php
 * @param string $serialized <p>
 * The string representation of the object.
 * </p>
 * @return mixed the original value unserialized.
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{

    $this->_uuid = unserialize($serialized)[0];
}
```